# Increment name through decorator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I'm trying to make a decorator for logging purposes. I try to increment the name of a log when the same decorator is called inside sub-function but fail to have a correct input. I also have some difficulty understanding my actual output.

```py
import datetime
import functools


def log(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.log_name += "." + func.__name__
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        duration = datetime.datetime.now() - start
        print(f"{wrapper.log_name }: {duration}")

    wrapper.log_name = "test"

    return wrapper


@log
def main_function():
    other_function()


@log
def other_function():
    print("i'm in the other function")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_function()
    main_function()
```

I got:

```
i'm in the other function
**test.other_function:** 0:00:00.000007
test.main_function: 0:00:00.000021
i'm in the other function
test.other_function.other_function: 0:00:00.000001
test.main_function.main_function: 0:00:00.000004
```

But I expected:

```
i'm in the other function
test.main_function.other_function: 0:00:00.000007
test.main_function: 0:00:00.000021
i'm in the other function
test.main_function.other_function: 0:00:00.000001
test.main_function: 0:00:00.000004
```

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Why did you expect `other_function.__name__` to be `"main_function.other_function"`?

Comment: in the `__main__` there is twice the same function call

Comment: @jonrsharpe i want the log_name variable to be the concatenation of the path with drive to call "other function" when the function is decorated; for calling "other_function", you go through "main_function" which call "other_function", so i want the log_name to be <base_log_name>.main_function.other_function. the idea is to get the possibility to compute flame graph after this

Comment: @cards there is two calls for testing purpose

Comment: You have two _separate_ `wrapper`s, each with its own `log_name`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, that's the problem, but do you know how can i achieve the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Used `inspect` library to get calling function info from the `stack`.
* Added `other_function2` just to check.

```
import datetime
import functools
import inspect

def log(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        # get previous callings from the stack
        previous_callings = []
        stack = inspect.stack()
        for i in range(2, len(stack), 2):
            if stack[i][3] != stack[0][3]: break
            previous_callings.append(stack[i - 1][3])

        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        duration = datetime.datetime.now() - start
        to_print = ['test'] + previous_callings[::-1] + [func.__name__]
        print(f"{'.'.join(to_print)}: {duration}")

    return wrapper

@log
def main_function():
    other_function()

@log
def other_function():
    print("i'm in the other function")
    other_function2()

@log
def other_function2():
    print("i'm in the other function 2")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_function()
    main_function()
```

Gives Output (Didn't bother to change the time format...)

```
i'm in the other function
i'm in the other function 2
test.main_function.other_function.other_function2: 0:00:00
test.main_function.other_function: 0:00:00
test.main_function: 0:00:00
i'm in the other function
i'm in the other function 2
test.main_function.other_function.other_function2: 0:00:00
test.main_function.other_function: 0:00:00
test.main_function: 0:00:00
```

Comment: thanks a lo for this proposition, but it will not work if i have a third level function